# I am new in java in my code here is an error "cannot find symbol "

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

I am following a Book in this book the code is given i tried to compile it  but it shows errors here is the Code-

```
  class TapeDeck {
    boolean canRecord = false;

    void playTape() {
        System.out.println("tape recording");
    }

    void recording() {
        System.out.println("tape recording");
    }
}
class TapeDeckTestDrive {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck( );
        t.canRecord = true;
        t.play();

        if (t.canRecord == true) {
            t.recordTape();
        }
    }
}
```

and an error is....

```
    TapeDeck.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                t.play();
                 ^
  symbol:   method play()
  location: variable t of type TapeDeck
TapeDeck.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                        t.recordTape();
                         ^
  symbol:   method recordTape()
  location: variable t of type TapeDeck
2 errors
```

Comment: `TapeDeck` doesn't have `play` and `recordTape` methods.

Comment: Your functions are playTape() and recording(). You're calling play() and recordTape().

Comment: after fixing it i have an  error like this.. 'Error: Main method not found in class TapeDeck, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application'

Comment: Just copy and paste this message into a search engine ...

Comment: Don't change the subject of your existing question. If you have a new one, then ask a new question. And as I already wrote: ***DO SOME RESEARCH***. Being new is no valid excuse for being lazy. Your questions have been asked millions of times, so go and look for them and learn from them.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `play()` is not a method of class `TapeDeck`. However, you do have the following method:

```
void playTape() {
    System.out.println("tape recording");
}
```

If this is the method that you meant, then change `t.play()` to `t.playTape()`. If not, you will need to create `play()` in `TapeDeck`.

Comment: *"then your code should compile"* This is wrong.

Comment: Or rather, _"this error should go away"_.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because you're trying to call methods that `TapeDeck` doesn't have: `play()` and `recordTape()`. Most likely the book you're referring to just didn't show the implementation for the sake of size.

You can just add those methods to your `TapeDeck` class, or change the methods you're calling from your main method to the ones already in your `TapeDeck` class (`playTape()` and `recording()`).